# Append Hint in Oracle

Tags: oracle, append, oracle10g, hint, global-temp-tables

I am inserting huge volume of records from one table into another table using insert into  using select statement in package. I am using multithreading in select statement.Shall I use /*+ APPEND NOLOGGING */ hint in the insert statement. Is it really improve performance and also is it good idea to create index on global temporary table in oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The performance improvements of the `APPEND` hint can be massive for multiple reasons. Enabling direct-path writes allows Oracle to avoid writing multiple copies of the data, such as redo, undo, and archive logs. Direct-path writes can also enable compression, automatic statistics collections, and other optimizations. But beware of the important downsides of direct-path writes: the changes are *not* recoverable until the next backup, and the table is completely locked until a `COMMIT`.

If you're already using multi-threading on the reads, you might as well use multi-threaded writes with a hint like `INSERT /*+ APPEND PARALLEL(8) */ ...`. But you might need to use `ENABLE_PARALLEL_DML` hint or enable parallel DML at the session level.

There's a good chance the `APPEND` hint won't initially improve performance because there are many limitations on direct-path writes, such as no the logging property (if your database is in archivelog mode), triggers, foreign keys, etc. (Note that `LOGGING` is *not* a hint, it is an object property.)

Look carefully at your execution plans to ensure you are getting direct-path writes. You should see an operation named `LOAD AS SELECT` instead of `LOAD TABLE CONVENTIONAL` to ensure direct-path writes are used. And you should see a `PX ...` operation before any operation you want parallelized.

If you're using a modern version of Oracle, the `Note` section of the execution plan may tell you why you're not getting direct-path writes or parallelism. And a SQL Monitor Report (generated through `DBMS_SQLTUNE.REPORT_SQL_MONITOR`) can help you identify problems with the degree of parallelism and other performance problems.

On many systems, you can improve `INSERT` performance by 100X or more, but it may take a lot of effort.

Comment: Thank you Jon Heller.I will check. I am using merge statement contains several joins. it is taking more time. I am analyzing now.